# What is the difference between aq\0aq and \0?

Tags: c, ascii

I think the title describes everything, but the story is
I'm re-implementing the [bzero](https://linux.die.net/man/3/bzero) function in c, and
that's where I encountered this `aq\0aq`
by some searching I understood that it has the same role as `\0`(which is a null character to determine the end of a string)
but I'm curious if there's any difference and what is the `aq`?

Comment: Just a typo probably, or some kind of an encoding problem. They mean `'\0'`.

Comment: [`man bzero`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bzero.3.html) from a better site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the aq?

It's an artifact left by converting groff (man pages, see `man 7 groff`) to html. It should be just `'\0'`. See `man bzero`.

https://github.com/mkerrisk/man-pages/blob/master/man3/bzero.3#L45

> ```
> by writing zeros (bytes containing \(aq\e0\(aq) to that area.
> ```